# Why is stacking a list of small tensors faster than updating a slice of a large tensor?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, tensor

I want to update slices of a tensor sequentially, basically iterating over multiple time steps. Naively, I thought that reserving the memory upfront and then updating a slice in that memory was faster than concatenating/stacking a list thereof in the end, but it seems as if I'm wrong. Any ideas why that is?

```py
import torch

batch_size = 256
time_steps = 50
channels = 3
width = 20
heigth = 20
device = 'cuda'

def reserve_memory():
    out_state = torch.zeros((batch_size, time_steps, channels, width, heigth), device=device)
    state = torch.ones((batch_size, channels, width, heigth), device=device)
    for step in range(time_steps):
        state = state * 1e-3
        out_state[:,step] = state

def stack_memory():
    out_state = []
    state = torch.ones((batch_size, channels, width, heigth), device=device)
    for step in range(time_steps):
        state = state * 1e-3
        out_state.append(state)
    out_state = torch.stack(out_state, 1)
```

```
%timeit -r 100 reserve_memory()
```

1.04 ms ± 49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%timeit -r 100 stack_memory()
```

707 µs ± 9.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: On my computer difference is much larger and still in favor of stacking. When I did `device = 'cpu'` it diminished (even stacking was a bit worse this time). Tested also **stacking batches** instead of time_steps and again difference decreased, but stacking was still better.

Comment: thanks for verifying it @dankal444. Still scratching my head on this one

Comment: The following tests show similar behavior: `timeit.timeit('for i in range(10): x[i:i+10] = torch.randn(10)', setup='import torch; x = torch.zeros(100)', number=1000)` is always slower than `timeit.timeit('torch.hstack([torch.randn(10) for _ in range(10)])', setup='import torch', number=1000)`.  Same if I use torch.ones(10).